# Flutter - How can I separate my listview by date

Tags: flutter, api

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUfjY.png)

How can I achieve this but instead of team A team B, I want to have dates for example:

This Month

- ListTile
- ListTile

..

December 2022

- ListTile
- ListTile

November 2021

- ListTile
- ListTile

October 2021

- ListTile
- ListTile

I am fetching data from API and I want to separate them like that. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Use [grouped_list](https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_list) package. You can divide your list of data according to any category, like date, name etc.